# Reach nested variable for angular interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I have the following which queries Firestore for a list, then takes that list and makes another query using the results as a parameter.  How can I reach those results with angular interpolation?

list of lists:

```
this.shopsCollection = afs.collection('stations', ref => ref.orderBy('StationtName'));
    this.shops = this.shopsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Shop;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
       const queues = this.afs.collection('projects', ref => ref.where('station', '==', data.StationtName)).valueChanges()
        .subscribe(data=>{
          console.log(data);

----------looking to use the data from the item variable---------

          const item = data.map(function (obj) {
            return obj.SKU;
          });
          console.log(item);

         })

        return { id, ...data };
      }))

    );
```

then my html:

```
 <li *ngFor="let shop of shops | async">
           {{shop.StationtName}} 

               <div *ngFor="let data of item">
                   {{data}}
               </div>         
 </li>
```

The console logs an array with the correct data on each loop, my ASSumption was I could simply add another ngFor inside to catch the values of each array.  Am I incorrect about that?  What is the best way to display my data?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
this.shops outputs an observable:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `this.shops`

Comment: I added the console log or this.shops, its an observable so I'm not sure how to check the output.